# How to generate this animated view of wave form?

Tags: animation

This official video of the song [Do I Wanna Know - Arctic Monkey](https://youtu.be/bpOSxM0rNPM) has a really cool minimalistic smooth flow of free-style drawings occasionally accompanied with wave forms of the audio. I wanted to know how to get at least the wavy patterns of the song. Any hints on how to generate these or what tools could have been possibly used, would be of great help.

I am a new user of this site, so please let me know if this is not the appropriate platform to ask.

Comment: The wave patterns are not the wave form of the audio. They look like simple sine wave additions - so you could draw them in any video editor.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a waveform, **it is an animation simulating one**. :o)

Most likely the shapes are it is in vector format, so you can morph it from state A to state B, etc.

There is not a simple way, it needs some work, for example you need to define the exact frame where you want Shape A and where you want Shape B. So make some timelines.

Then use vector-based animation software. Either After effects or the free one Synfig.